# Branching cryptoswift for 2.3

Tags: swift, git, cocoapods, cryptoswift

I'm trying to use cocoapods to install crypto swift and am having trouble with what to place in the pod file.

I have tried:

```
pod 'CryptoSwift', :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/tree/swift2", :branch => 'master'
```

And I get the error:

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/tree/swift2/' not found
```

I'm not sure how to target the particular version needed. In the git instructions it states for Swift 2.2, 2.3: branch swift2 version <= 0.5.2. I can't seem how to target 0.5.2 syntactically, I also tried:

```
pod 'CryptoSwift', '<=0.5.2' :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", :branch => 'swift2'
```

and I got errors about unexpected commas.

Comment: The repository is `https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift`. `tree/swift2` helps you browse github but is not part of the address of the git repository.

Comment: @Benoit Ok, but how to target the version for swift 2.3? i.e. <= 0.5.2?

Comment: Have you tried `pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.5.2'` ?

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti I have tried the following: pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.5.2' :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", :branch => 'master', this gives me an error pointing to the unexpected : before branch

Comment: Try without the branch option. The version 0.5.2 is made for Swift 2.3. Just point to that one. Doesn't make sense to point a tag and a branch at the same time

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Ok I updated and removed the branch part: pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.5.2' :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift"  now I get an error pointing to the unexpected : before git

Comment: Remove git. I said the exact line you should use.

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Ok, thank you sorted, I didn't realise I didn't need to specify the source

Comment: I did say this below about 5 mins ago...

Comment: @JacobKing I said it 5 minutes before you did. Is there any problem? I don't care, you can have the accepted answer

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Oops I didn't see that, I apologise. Odd that the OP beat around the bush so much even though the answer was given so quickly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The podfile string I am using for my CryptoSwift project (Swift 2.3) is the following:

`pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.5.2'`

This is working for me.